# ! Argument of \align* has an extra }

Tags: align, braces

When I run the following code:

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Here, } i = 2, 5, \text{ and } 6, \text{ because observations 2, 5, and 6 } & \text{are the closest (by Euclidian distance)} \\
P(Y = Red \mid X = (0, 0, 0)) &= \frac{1}{3} \sum_{i \in N_0} (i = Red) \\
&= \frac{1}{3}(1 + 0 + 1) \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \\
\text{and} \\
P(Y = Green \mid X = (0, 0, 0)) &= \frac{1}(3}\sum_{i \in N_0} (j = Green) \\
&= \frac{1}{3}(0 + 1 + 0) \\
&= \frac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Argument of \align* has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.248 ... Green \mid X = (0, 0, 0)) &= \frac{1}(3}
                                                  \sum_{i \in N_0} (j = Gree...
```

From what I have read, this error does not always mean you literally have an extra }.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach in such situations is to comment and uncomment various lines, or parts of lines, and recompile repeatedly to see when the error goes away and comes back.

Doing that helped me find

```
P(Y = Green \mid X = (0, 0, 0)) &= \frac{1}(3}\sum_{i \in N_0} (j = Green) \\
```

specifically

```
\frac{1}(3}
```

That is a `(` which should be `{`.